# Свойство Size что это?

Tags: c#, winapi

Начал читать про Windows Forms и наткнулся на такой текст:

> Для установки размеров формы можно использовать такие свойства как Width/Height или Size. Width/Height принимают числовые значения, как в вышеприведенном примере. При установке размеров через свойство Size, нам надо присвоить свойству объект типа Size:
>
> ```
> this.Size = new Size(200,150);
> ```
>
> Объект Size в свою очередь принимает в конструкторе числовые значения для установки ширины и высоты.

Я не понимаю как полю, либо свойству(без разницы) можно выделять память? Объясните что это вообще такое?

Comment: Причем здесь память? Это размеры контрола в пикселях о_О

Comment: `Я не понимаю как полю, либо свойству(без разницы) можно выделять память?` - поле это ссылка на объект. Память выделяется на создание объекта, и ссылка на созданный объект сохраняется в поле

Comment: А где в цитате говорится про выделение памяти?

Comment: спрашивают, наверное, из-за new, потому что он подразумевает выделение памяти в куче в большинстве случаев

Comment: Но ведь мы когда что то меняем в уже существующем объекте,мы просто присваиваем его свойству новое значение

Comment: а что,свойствам можно перевыделять память с помощью new?

Comment: свойство это указатель на область памяти (объект). вы не "пересоздаете" "свойство" в форме, а заменяете значение этого указателя на новое

Comment: а Size в данном случае это что?

Comment: @Whitehorse ссылка на конкретный экземпляр класса отличный от null.

Answer (score 0):

Все визуальные компоненты WinForms наследуются от типа `Control` (да, форма тоже), поэтому дальше буду говорить именно о нем.

Технически, размер контрола задается приватным полем типа `Size`, которое доступно через одноименное свойство `Control.Size`. Так как тип `Size` - структура (перечитать про различия между Value Type и Reference Type), то при доступе через свойство `Control.Size` вы получаете копию данных, следовательно задать новое значение через данное свойство можно только путем записи новой структуры, что и показано в вашем примере.

Кроме того есть отдельные свойства `Control.Width` и `Control.Heght`, которые возвращают и задают значения компонент внутреннего поля `Size` напрямую.

Какой из вариантов использовать - решать только вам.

---

по поводу `new` - в данном случае эта конструкция только инициализирует структуру, память под которую уже выделена. (и еще раз перечитать про различия между Value Type и Reference Type)